# Can't access a control from LoginTemplate in LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code in aspx page

```
<asp:LoginView ID="loginView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">

          <LoggedInTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnWatchlist" runat="server" Text="+ Watchlist"  />
                <asp:Button ID="btnPM" runat="server" Text="PM" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnReport" runat="server" Text="Report" />
          </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Code in aspx.cs(Codebehind) to acccess the button id's

```
Button watchList = (Button)loginView1.FindControl("btnWatchlist");
Button pm = (Button)loginView1.FindControl("btnPM");
Button report = (Button)loginView1.FindControl("btnReport");
Button edit = (Button)loginView1.FindControl("btnEdit");
```

watchList,pm,report,edit is getting null values.Any mistake in my code?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stupid question, but are you signed in to your site? When testing I noted that the controls are only visible when signed in, so using FindControl in Page_Load would not find the controls unless I was signed in.